# How do conditionally add or remove members from Rails 3.2 Arel method chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I am duplicating my `includes`, `where`, `order`, and `paginate` methods because I don't know if there is a block for Arel chains or better way to make this DRY. Is there something that makes it easy to test for the specialty_id or facility_id in params without using a long `where` string with ternary operators?

```
class << self
  def list(options = {})

    facility_id  = options[:facility_id]  || nil
    keywords     = options[:keywords]     || nil
    page         = options[:page]         || nil
    specialty_id = options[:specialty_id] || nil
    jobs         = self.arel_table

    unless keywords.nil?
      keywords = keywords.downcase.tr_s('^a-z0-9 ', '').tr_s(' ', '\%')
    end

    if !specialty_id.blank?
      approved.
          includes(:facility, :specialties, :videos).
          where(jobs[:name].matches("%#{keywords}%")).
          where(specialties: {id: specialty_id}).
          order(jobs[:name]).
          paginate(page: page, per_page: 20)
    elsif !facility_id.blank?
      approved.
          includes(:facility, :specialties, :videos).
          where(jobs[:name].matches("%#{keywords}%")).
          where(facilities: {id: facility_id}).
          order(jobs[:name]).
          paginate(page: page, per_page: 20)
    else
      approved.
          includes(:facility, :specialties, :videos).
          where(jobs[:name].matches("%#{keywords}%")).
          order(jobs[:name]).
          paginate(page: page, per_page: 20)
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = approved
query = query.includes(:facility, :specialties, :videos)
query = query.where(jobs[:name].matches("%#{keywords}%")) if jobs[:name].present?
query = query. ...
query = query.paginate(page: page, per_page: 20)
query.to_a
```

Comment: I tried this before but it only used the `query.paginate` line. Let me check and see what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to chain these together to build it up prior to execution.

Something like this should be possible:

```
scoped.tap do |query|
  query.
    approved.
    includes(:facility, :specialties, :videos).
    where(jobs[:name].matches("%#{keywords}%"))

  query.where(specialties: { id: specialty_id }) if specialty_id.present?
  query.where(facilities: { id: facility_id })   if facility_id.present?

  query.order(jobs[:name]).paginate(page: page, per_page: 20)
end
```

For more info on `scoped` see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7a80ac0162ae84cf22c91646690ad18916a66274/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L30).

Comment: Awesome. That's the block I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, tap doesn't work with `will_paginate`. :( It must have its scope crossed.

Comment: Also, if it's a ```will_paginate``` incompatibility, you could look into [```kaminari```](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

Comment: Yes, **Ruby 1.9.3p193** to be exact. If I remove the `pagination` method, this works perfectly. I get the error `undefined method 'total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation>` with it.

Comment: Yeah, ```total_pages``` is a ```will_paginate``` method. If you're not paginating then you won't have access to it.

Comment: Tap ignores all the query statements inside the block. I had to go back to `query = query.method`.